# Reflection principle: can any property of a set (model) be reflected?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, infinity, reflection

Can any property of a set be reflected? If no, why? Is there some sort of requirement that must be fulfilled? I've read on the Wikipedia page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle ,that in ZF the property of the 'class of all sets' being reflected causes some paradoxical implications. I am relatively new to set theory and as of recently interested in the reflection principle. I would like questions about it answered, and any misconceptions cleared.

Comment: How is "I am the class of all sets" formalized as a first-order property?

Comment: Apologies I should've worded it more carefully. What is really meant it the property of holding all sets. This is seen when the reflection principle is applied to the universe. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle